# Proof involving inequalities

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

I was wondering if we have the following $(\Bbb R,\le)$ then if i was to prove anti-symetric property would the following be sufficient, Let $a,b\in \Bbb R$ then if $a\le b$ and $b\le a$ then $a=b$ is it enough to say this is true by the definition of $\le$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

since the condition for anti-symmetry is

$\forall a,b \in X\ \ aRb\ \wedge bRa \implies a = b  $ where $R$ is the relation from $X*X \to X$

and the equality can be trivially stated from the definition of $\leq$